# Why can't I access my widget settings in Twitter when it works for everyone else?

Tags: twitter, widgets

For the last couple of weeks I've been unable to access my widget settings for my Twitter account. When clicking Widgets on the Settings page, I get this error:
[image: Screenshot showing the error.]

My widgets are still working, but I am unable to access that page to <strike>create new or</strike> configure existing widgets. (Update: I can access https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new to create new widgets). Other users I have asked do not have this problem.

I have made several help requests through [Twitters official help page](https://support.twitter.com/forms/general) but all I get back is automated responses that do not address the issue. These responses prompt me to reply if the issue still isn't fixed, which I do, but there is never a follow-up response.

What I've tried:

- Using Chrome and Chromium on two different computers, in both normal and incognito mode.
- Fresh install of Firefox, with no extensions, on two different computers.
- Chrome browser on my Nexus 7 tablet.
- Internet Explorer on a computer that has never accessed Twitter before.

None of these work. It's like Twitter has blocked me from accessing my widget settings! What's wrong?

**Update**: [Sounds like I'm not the only one.](https://twittercommunity.com/t/cannot-access-https-twitter-com-settings-widgets/22391)

Comment: For what it's worth, I can get to that page with no issue. It sounds like it might be a bug that Twitter needs to fix.