# How and where do I report a problem with Twitter that will likely be looked at, not ignored?

Tags: twitter

[I cannot access my widget settings on Twitter.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/67131/40129) I have used the [How can I get help?](https://support.twitter.com/forms) page to submit several help requests, but I never get back anything other than automated responses that suggest nothing that would resolve the problem. These automated responses say to reply with more information, which I do, but I never hear back from them.

How and where do I report a problem with Twitter that will likely be looked at, not ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Twitter Community](https://twittercommunity.com/) has Twitter staff who are willing to investigate reported problems.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot guarantee that it will be dealt with (remember:  when you don't pay for a service, you are the product, not the customer).

But you could try posting it on Twitter itself, to see if there are more people out there with the problem and use community momentum to get a response.